# Updating PS Modules

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

We have some 200+ standalone virtual servers each practically identical, and there are various scripts we need to run against some or all of these at points.

To date I've been messing around with the profile but modules are a far neater solution so this is my next project.

The only question I don't seem to be able to find an answer for is how to update it once it's installed. Is there some built-in way to do this or do I need to set up my own means of copying in updated files?

Servers are Win2008R2 running PowerShell 4

Comment: So you have a module present on multiple machines and you are curious if there is another way to update the file aside from copying the module to the other machines?

Comment: Pretty much. I can put together a script to download and replace the files but there's some hurdles I need to cross so just checking if there's a "proper" way of doing it first.

Comment: You could have a scheduled task on all these machines that "checks" the module "version" and replaces the file.

Comment: If I have to put together my own solution I'll set up a function in the module that checks for and applies an update so I can push out an update check whenever I need to add or change anything.

Comment: Or you can have all the clients connect to a central share (where the modules are stored) to read the modules. But then they need to be able to access that share.. Something like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/08/powertip-import-a-powershell-module-from-a-shared-location.aspx).

Comment: Standalone servers with external IP addresses. They aren't in a network but I digress, I only want to know if there is an official method of updating modules. In hindsight this is probably more a SuperUser question...

Comment: In this situation I would use a repository to avoid any possible conflicts then from each server set up a task which will routinely pull from that repository.